# All TableRows are rerendered each time a row is selected with React and material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a code snippet like this

```
<Table selectable onRowSelection={this.onRecordSelected} bodyStyle={tableBodyStyle}>
        <TableBody deselectOnClickaway={false} showRowHover displayRowCheckbox={false}>
          {this.props.taskRecords.map((row, index) => (
            <TableRow key={row.get('id')} selected={this.state.selectedRecordRowId === index}>
              <TableRowColumn>{row.getIn(['task', 'name'])}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{row.getIn(['task', 'description'])}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{row.get('status')}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{row.get('log')}</TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
</Table>
```

I checked the source code of `TableRow` and `TableRowColumn`, I found they didn't implement `shouldComponentUpdate` method. I understand they would be rerendered when any state is changed.

I tried to use `pure` function in `recompose` library to purify these to components.

```
const TableRow = pure(require('material-ui/lib/table/table-row'));
const TableRowColumn = pure(require('material-ui/lib/table/table-row-column'));
```

They were still rerendered
[image]

In my understanding, components after purified wouldn't be rerendered anymore if given `props` are not changed.  In this case, all props are either Immutable objects from `Immutable.js` or functions.

Is there any way to prevent it from rerendering when I select any row?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution.

```
<Table selectable onRowSelection={this.onRecordSelected} bodyStyle={tableBodyStyle}>
        <TableBody deselectOnClickaway={false} showRowHover displayRowCheckbox={false}>
          {this.props.taskRecords.map((row, index) => (
            <PureRecordRow key={row.get('id')} selected={this.state.selectedRecordRowId === index}>
              <TableRowColumn>{row.getIn(['task', 'name'])}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{row.getIn(['task', 'description'])}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{row.get('status')}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{row.get('log')}</TableRowColumn>
            </PureRecordRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
 </Table>
```

I created a new component `PureRecordRow` which extends the `TableRow` with custom `shouldComponentUpdate` method:

```
class PureRecordRow extends TableRow{
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context)
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.hovered !== nextState.hovered || this.props.selected !== nextProps.selected;
  }
}
```

Comment: cannot extend TableRow

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes - `render` function will be called each time in `TableRow` and `TableRowColumn` if their parent component will be rerendered, but it is not so bad, because `render` function do not change your RealDOM each time, so it is not so bad for your application performance. 
But, if you really want to prevent that because of reasons, you can for example create new component `MyRow` and render it instead of `TableRow + TableRowColumn`.

So, your code will be like:

```
<Table selectable onRowSelection={this.onRecordSelected} bodyStyle={tableBodyStyle}>
    <TableBody deselectOnClickaway={false} showRowHover displayRowCheckbox={false}>
      {this.props.taskRecords.map((row, index) => (
        <MyRow key={index} row={row} isSelected={this.state.selectedRecordRowId === index} />
      ))}
    </TableBody>
</Table>
```

And in `MyRow` component you can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` (or `PureRenderMixin`) and render real material-ui components:

```
render() {
    var isSelected = this.props.isSelected;
    var row = this.props.row;
    return <TableRow key={row.get('id')} selected={isSelected}>
          <TableRowColumn>{row.getIn(['task', 'name'])}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{row.getIn(['task', 'description'])}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{row.get('status')}</TableRowColumn>
          <TableRowColumn>{row.get('log')}</TableRowColumn>
    </TableRow>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! The problem with this approach is after wrapping the `TableRow` in `MyRow`, the onSelect handler of `TableRow` is not working properly.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't see any `onSelect` handlers available in `TableRow` component =/ I've checked official documentation and https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/Table/TableRow.js source file